# Are there any software/game differences in the editions of Kingdom Hearts?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I'm looking at the various Japanese-language editions of Kingdom Hearts, and there's quite a few available, including:

- (original)
- Ultimate Hits
- Final Mix
- Final Mix Ultimate Hits
- Final Mix Platinum Limited Edition

Apart from the packaging, are there any differences in the actual games?  Is the software on the disc identical for each of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Final Mix is an updated version of the original which adds more content.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_(video_game)#Final_Mix)

When the first game was brought to North American and European territories, they added more content in the form of enemies and cutscenes. Final Mix brings those updates to Japan as well, and added *even more* content on top of that.

The Limited Edition is the same game as Final Mix, but it includes extra physical goodies.

[Ultimate Hits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Hits) is a budget range by Sony; that is, those games are simply reprints released at lower prices.