# What's different in the 3 versions of Kingdom Hearts 2?

Tags: version-differences, kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

More of less the same thing i asked [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/194752/30879) but this time referring to *Kingdom Hearts 2* as i have played the PAL Release on PS2 and would like to know the differences between that and *Final Mix* and what may have been added to that in *2.5 HD Remix*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a lot of differences between Kingdom Hearts 2 and the Final Remix so I'll just list the major ones:

### Differences between Kingdom Hearts 2 and Final Remix

- New difficulty mode (critical mode)
- English voice acting and Japanese text/subtitles
- Higher definition textures
- New mini-game which unlocks special items (puzzle)
- New heartless colours
- New cutscenes
- New weapons
- New accessories
- Additional battles
- Filling the Drive Gauge is easier
- "Theater Mode" for re-watching cutscenes
- Secret ending video
- Bunch of balance changes

### Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX

- Includes Kingdom Hearts II Final Mix and Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep Final Mix
- Further improved graphics
- 3+ hours of high definition cutscenes with Kingdom Hearts Re:coded

Answer (score 0):

The differences are, in the final mix version (the original PS2 version) is a japan exclusive game the text is going to be in Japanese also you can get a PreModded ISO of it to have an english patch to run it on emulation which is good cause they did some censorship on the pirates of the carribbean world on the PS3 version. The PS3 HD 2.5 version comes with an official translation of both Kingdom Hearts 2 Final Mix and Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep Final Mix, and they improve the textures (yeah no fake improvements geniune new textures) most notably in BBS cause they had to compress them for the PSP port (assumely It could've been originally like that) the H.U.D has a H.D 1 for 1 recreation theres no differences between the two H.U.Ds in the Games other than looking less jaggy, The H.U.D has also been made to look nicer in Kingdom Hearts 2 Final Mix, overall this is a good port of Kingdom Hearts 2 final mix and Kingdom hearts Birth By sleep final mix.