# Is there any reason not to play Final Mix in Kingdom Hearts 1.5?

Tags: kingdom-hearts, kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

I've recently bought Kingdom Hearts 1.5 for the PS3, having never played a Kingdom hearts game before, and the game comes with both the standard version and a version called Final Mix. It appears that the final mix original release was to bring some things from the english version into the Japanese version, and added some new items and enemies?

What are the differences between the regular version over the Final Mix version?

Comment: You might want to reword your question to ask for the differences between the two game versions instead, as this question is currently getting close votes as 'primarily opinion-based', probably because of 'reason not to / want to play'.

Comment: I edited the question so it is not opinion based anymore. If this get closed because some voters that do not pay attention, feel free to vote for re-opening

Comment: I am not convinced that the edit made by @Mathias711 preserved the intent of the original question. I highly doubt the accepted answer will ever change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Final Mix has new items, enemies, abilities etc. It is a much more better version than the original, although the original is not bad either. This mix is more of an upgrade version of normal.

Comment: This answer is primarily opinion based, as demonstrated by *"It is a **much more better** version than the original, although the original is **not bad either**. "*

Answer (score 1):

So one thing to note is that the PS3 version KH 1.5 HD Remix does not actually come with both versions of the game. It only includes the Final Mix version (plus some additional updates; [see this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/194754/15643)).

Included on the disc are 2 different games, plus cut-scenes from another. The two games are *Kingdom Hearts Final Mix HD*, and *Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories HD*, with cut-scenes from *Kingdom Hearts 358/2*.

That said, I would highly recommend starting with *Kingdom Hearts Final Mix* because the other games require the context of the first both chronologically and in plot and story.